# Botão voltar deleta o fragment no main activity

Tags: android, fragment

Olá, tudo bem? Eu estou fazendo um fragment que vai servidor como uma especie de menu cards na interface inicial. Eu fiz com que toda vez que o app abrir Ele crie essa interface dentro de uma ConstrainsLayout, porém quando eu abro ela e clico em voltar ela desaparece e só fica o bottomNavBar e o Constrains vázio...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_nav_bar);

        cardButtonID = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardButtonID);
        animationMenu();

//chamando a UI
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainViewId, new MainPageFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o seu fragment está chamando o o método onStop.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onResume() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onPause() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onSavedInstanceState() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onStop() chamado");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Ciclo", "Activity: Metodo onDestroy() chamado");
}
```

Insira este código em seu fragment e digite Ciclo em seu logcat, possivelmente, está sendo chamado o método onStop e com isso os valores na memória estão sendo deletados.